# ASP:DataGrid displaying columns twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I want to have bound columns in my `DataGrid` object. The code was working fine before I added them, but now I get duplicate columns, and one column in particular I don't want at all.  Here is the ASP:

```
        <ASP:DataGrid id="UserDataGrid" AutoGenerateColums="False" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:EditCommandColumn CancelText="Cancel" EditText="Edit" UpdateText="Update" HeaderText="Edit item">
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False"/>
                </asp:EditCommandColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="false" SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="UserID" HeaderText="User ID" ReadOnly="false" SortExpression="UserID" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="FullName" HeaderText="User Name" ReadOnly="false" SortExpression="FullName" />
            </Columns>
        </ASP:DataGrid>
```

And the code behind:

```
    DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();
    dtUsers = dataAccessManager.ExecuteSQLForTable("SELECT * FROM tblUser");
    UserDataGrid.DataSource = dtUsers;
    UserDataGrid.DataBind();
```

Everything I've read says setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to false should fix the problem, but it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you provided, `AutoGenerateColumns` appears to be spelled incorrectly. It should work fine if you fix that.

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="UserDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
```

Comment: So many facepalms.  I thought VS2010 would complain about properties that don't match with the class?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:1

Nomally the **autogeneratecolumns** property is true and if we bind a DataGrid to a table,the DataGrid will show all the columns of the table. Only when you set the **autogeneratecolumns**  to false, then you may let the DataGrid to show columns that you assigned.

But According to you this is not working.Ok

Solution :2

You can hide DataGrid Columns

```
 DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();
    dtUsers = dataAccessManager.ExecuteSQLForTable("SELECT * FROM tblUser");
    UserDataGrid.DataSource = dtUsers;
    UserDataGrid.DataBind();
    //Right Below line for hide columns
    UserDataGrid.Columns[0].Visible = false;//Hide First column of the DataGrid 
    UserDataGrid.Columns[1].Visible = false;//Hide Second column of the DataGrid 
    UserDataGrid.Columns[2].Visible = false;//Hide Third column of the DataGrid
```

Solution :3

You can Remove DataGrid Columns

```
 DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();
    dtUsers = dataAccessManager.ExecuteSQLForTable("SELECT * FROM tblUser");
    UserDataGrid.DataSource = dtUsers;
    UserDataGrid.DataBind();
    //Right Below line for Remove columns

    UserDataGrid.Columns[0].Remove(); //Remove First column of the DataGrid 
    UserDataGrid.Columns[1].Remove(); //Remove Second column of the DataGrid 
    UserDataGrid.Columns[2].Remove(); //Remove Third column of the DataGrid
```

Best Wishes